# Should I use Unit or leave out the return type for my scala method?

Tags: scala, void, return-type

I am not sure what the difference is between specifying Unit as the return type of my scala method or leaving out the return type altogether. What is the difference?

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Implicit `Unit` return type:

```
def f() {println("ABC")}
```

Explicit `Unit` return type:

```
def g(): Unit = {println("ABC")}
```

Return type inferred from the last method expression, still `Unit` because this is the type of `println`, but confusing:

```
def h() = println("ABC")
```

All the methods above are equivalent. I would prefer `f()` because the lack of `=` operator after method signature alone is enough for me. Use explicit `: Unit` when you want to extra document the method. The last form is confusing and actually treated as a warning in [intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea).

The `=` operator is crucial. If it is present it means: "*please return whatever the last statement returns*" in method body. Obviously you cannot use this syntax for `abstract` methods. If it is not, `Unit` is assumed.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. The code you shared elicits another question: why are you allowed to omit the `=` sign in `f` and `g`?

Comment: If your function return `Unit`, you can omit the `=` sign. Any function define without a `=` sign returns `Unit`

Comment: Because in `Unit` functions the `=` is optional. However it is mandatory for all other types as they actually return something

Comment: If you explicitly specify the return type (whatever this type might be) you HAVE to use the `=` sign. Hence `def g(): Unit {println("ABC")}` doesn't compile, but def `g(): Unit = {println("ABC")}` does! And just FYI here is the link to the [style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/).

Comment: @agilesteel: yes, actually user *4e6* corrected that but rolled the correction afterwards, don't know why. Thanks for both of you.

Comment: "Explicit is better than Implicit". I follow this principal.

Comment: "Unit-returning procedures" are considered as BAD in official Scala documentation, basically because of the need of extra thought. It better be explicit.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/cheatsheets/

Answer (score 15):

The special syntax for procedures (methods returning *Unit*) was a mistake. Don't use it. It is confusing and dangerous for beginners with a Java/C(++) background. And it is a unnecessary special treatment. Always use the equal sign, with and without type inference (the latter should only be used for private members):

```
def foo(): Unit = someCodeReturningUnit()

private def bar() = someCodeReturningUnit()
```

Comment: The [style guide section](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#void_methods) should be updated if you are right about the "unnecessary special treatment".

Comment: @agilesteel There has always been controversy about that section.

Comment: The style guide [says](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations#procedure-syntax): "Avoid the procedure syntax, as it tends to be confusing for very little gain in brevity."

Answer (score 6):

The Scala community is divided about it. On the one hand, not using explicit return types means you can easily forget the `=` sign, which results in errors that are often annoying to track. On the other hand, `Unit`-returning methods having a different syntax puts them in a separate category, which pleases some people.

Personally, I'd rather this syntax would go away -- the errors resulting from missing `=` *are* annoying to track. But it's not even deprecated, so I'd rather take advantage of it than just suffer the problems of its existence.

So, use whatever you wish. There's going to be people criticizing your choice either way, and people praising it either way.